The etymology of the word 'anus' as in for 'old woman'?
I apologise if it may seem like this is some prank post as it's my first but it is something I've been wondering about for a while now. When I was taking Latin lessons in high school I remember having to learn tables of words for inflection. I am 49yo now and for the German language I still remember for eg. "Aus,bei,mit,nach,seit,von,zu" as being dative prepositions.
Then I vaguely remember a Latin word table which had the words 'cadex' (wood) and 'anus' (old woman) in it. I've tried to find this table but have not been able to. All I know is it had to do with inflection.
But.. Over the course of the past years I've often wondered about the (I'm aware) comical relation between the Latin word for old woman being 'anus' and the fact that if one visualises a (modern day use version?) of the word anus I think of a toothless old woman. I know having researched this that 'anus' actually also means 'ring' but I'm profoundly curious about the 'real' etymology of the word.
Is there any way to find out or is someone here able to say anything about the apparent adjective link between the word 'anus' and the visual connotation of a toothless old woman and how this fits in the etymology of the word? Was it a pun? Is there a link at all? Or is it just a coincidence and/or my seemingly dirty mind playing tricks with me?
I really do apologise as I'm aware it may seem like I'm taking the piss here but I assure you I am not and it's an honest and very real question I would like to see answered.
Thank you.

Welcome HNQ friends, fancy seeing you under this question!

The word anus "old woman" is unrelated to ānus "ring".
The former has a short initial vowel and is a fourth declension feminine noun and so declines identically to manus "hand", just without the initial m-. The latter has a long initial vowel and is a second declension masculine noun and so declines identically to rōmānus "Roman" without the initial rōm-.
De Vaan derives both from separate PIE roots. The former from a form of *h₂en-H-o- (although this would require a little massaging to get into a form that is fourth declension), and the latter from *h₁eh₂n-o- (which is perfectly regular, and has cognates in Goidelic and possible Armenian). There is no reason to believe the roots *h₂en- and *h₁eh₂n- are related (it's also possible that in the latter case the *n is actually a suffix and not part of the root at all).
So no, there's no reason to believe there is any idea of toothless old women's mouths resembling rings, at any stage of the language, although that may serve as a mnemonic for students.

Thank you for your answer. I must admit most goes over my head as -even though I have a Masters in Philosophy- it's so linguisticly technical I have no frame of reference to relate it to but I do honestly appreciate it.
However if I read you correctly you explain why there is no correlation between the essentialy two different words but not what the actual etymology of the word anus for old woman is.
So following your explanation the PIE root refers to a circular shape but what is the referential to old woman? Is it from annum (years) and is a circle essentially not a cycle as well?

@WishPlay the PIE root in the first case means "old woman". It's not known any further back than that. But no, neither one is related to annus (year).

@WishPlay basically the answer is just that both words come from separate roots. Neither is related to annus.

Tristan Not to be rude but yes, that much I understood already but it's not an answer to my OQ which was what the etymology of anus was. As it seems that remains unknown.

@WishPlay no, the etymology of anus is not unknown. De Vaan's etymological dictionary derives it from PIE *h₂en-H-o-

Sorry, I have no idea what those declensions(?) mean other than that involuntarily and in a very  childish way I again connotate it to an anus. In all seriousness though, I'm not a linguists but didn't @hobbs already confirmed there is no known etymology for the Latin 'anus'?

No, that is absolutely 100% not what I said at all.

@hobbs I'm really sorry but as said I'm not a linguists and all this jargon is not something I can understand. I'll probably be wrong but when I think of an answer to the question of the etymology of 'anus' I expected an answer similar to 'purgatory' apparently having an element of 'cleansing' in it giving the meaning and my understanding much more depth. You wrote 'it's not known further than that' which to me reads as. 'Unknown'.

@WishPlay we know what the roots in question are, but we don't know their meanings

@Tristan So am I correct in understanding that 'etymology' does not necessarily mean one can trace back a word to a 'meaning' or a deviation or connotation?

semantic change is tricky, meaning we can often work out what the earlier form of a word must have been, even when we can't be confident on the original meaning. This is usually included within the meaning of the word etymology

@WishPlay To come to that conclusion you would have to completely ignore the entire rest of the sentence. You seem to be making an extreme effort not to see an answer that's in front of you.

@Tristan thanks for the clarification. hobbs I’m pretty confident on a linguistic level my comment was no conclusion but an open question. I really love a debate but it seems my questions (which is what philosophers are trained to do) turn this debate into an argument. I can only conclude apparently this forum is for 'insiders' only whereas I only drifted here in pursuit of an idea or question. I don't think I belong here. I'm sorry to have bothered you all but I do wish to leave you with a reflection on why you think it is that asking questions leads to such emotional distress. Thank you.
